# display different 3D objects based on detected image's index in image database arcore

Tags: java, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have created an imgdb file consisting of images that I want to detect in arcore sceneform. Once I detect an image, I wish to display an augmented 3D object where the image was detected. Now, I wish to display a different 3D object depending on which image within the imgdb file was detected.

Something like this? But my app keeps crashing if I do this in the AugmentedImageNode.java file.

```
public class AugmentedImageNode extends AnchorNode {

  private static final String TAG = "AugmentedImageNode";
  public AugmentedImage image;
  private static CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable> ulCorner;

  public AugmentedImageNode(Context context) {
      int imagenumber;
      imagenumber = image.getIndex();
          if (imagenumber == 0) {
              if (ulCorner == null) {
                  ulCorner =
                          ModelRenderable.builder()
                                  .setSource(context, Uri.parse("models/tinker.sfb"))
                                  .build();
                   }
          }

          if (imagenumber == 1) {
              if (ulCorner == null) {
                  ulCorner =
                          ModelRenderable.builder()
                                  .setSource(context, Uri.parse("models/borderfence-small.sfb"))
                                  .build();
              }
          }


      }
```

Here are the logcat details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYxuj.png)

Comment: [Edit] the question and show errors or crashlogs, please.

Comment: dont add images for the code or error trace always add text